# how to not detect \ as escaping character in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, escaping, atom-editor

I was trying to make a snippet, for atom, using the following code,

```
'.source.cpp':
'Template':
'prefix': 'codetemplate'
'body':'''
 /* some code here */
 #define endl '\n'
'''
```

and I need exactly `#define endl '\n'` in my template. But what coffescript does is, that it reads `\n` as newline character. I tried using `\\n` but that just gives `n` as output and not the backslash.

How can I have that backslash in my template.

Comment: Have you tried adding more `\\`?

Comment: Yeah I tried with `\\n` but that gave `n` as output, and `\\\n` again gave newline as output

Comment: Thanks, using `4` backslashes , i.e, `\\\\n` does the work. I actually didn't try that as I thought that it will just print `n` as in case of two backslashes.

But now, I'm interesting in knowing what happened when i used 4 backslashes